Moodle - how to create a simple Module activity
Moodle - how to create a simple Module activity, with just a button.
The button should be displayed to user and upon clicking the button, an email will be triggered to admins.
Need expert advice on this and that will help me build further on the activity. Thank you in advance.

The URL activity is probably the simplest
Make a copy of the URL code. Replace references to URL with the name of your plugin. Replace the actual url with a button to a page in the activity that sends the email.
https://docs.moodle.org/404/en/URL_resource
